# Is it possible to define default mapping for an inner object in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have a document like this:

```
{
    "events" : [
        { 
         "event_id" : 123,
         "props" : {
              "version": "33"
        },
        {
         "event_id" : 124,
         "props" : {
              "version": "44a"
         }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to specify that the `events.props.version` be mapped to some type?

I've tried:

```
{
  "template" : "logstash-*",
  ...
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
       "properties" : {
         "events.props.version" : { "type" : "string" }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at `mapping` API in elasticsearch [Mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html).

To set any analyzer in the inner element we need to consider each and every inner field as a separate properties set. try the following

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "events": {
                "properties": {
                    "event_id": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "keyword"
                    },
                    "props": {
                        "properties": {
                            "version": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if this not works please provide me you mapping.

Comment: Thanks! Would this work even if "events" is an array?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but you need to use the "object" type:

From the doc ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/mapping-object-type.html ) if you want to map

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "person" : {
            "name" : {
                "first_name" : "Shay",
                "last_name" : "Banon"
            },
            "sid" : "12345"
        },
        "message" : "This is a tweet!"
    }
}
```

you can write:

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
            "person" : {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "name" : {
                        "type" : "object",
                        "properties" : {
                            "first_name" : {"type" : "string"},
                            "last_name" : {"type" : "string"}
                        }
                    },
                    "sid" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
                }
            },
            "message" : {"type" : "string"}
        }
    }
}
```